# Inbalance of ()

Tags: php

For some reason I'm receiving a syntax error for the following line with an imbalance of parenthesis and I don't see the reason.

```
if(isset($this->uri->segment(3)) AND ((empty($this->uri->segment(3))||($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE)||(trim($this->uri->segment(3)) == '')))
```

Comment: There are 12 opening but only 11 closing parentheses in it.

Comment: By the way: [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) do only work with variables.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(
  isset(
    $this->uri->segment(3)
  ) AND (
    (
      empty(
        $this->uri->segment(3)
      )||(
        $this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE
      )||(
        trim(
          $this->uri->segment(3)
        ) == ''
      )
    )
  )
```

You forgot to close your `if`.

Comment: Upvote limit reached but that formatting in itself tells how to resolve such issue :)

Comment: The logic makes no sense, `empty()` takes care of the other two conditions. `if (empty($var) || $var === FALSE)` is utterly redundant.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Not my problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Nice attitude. I though we were here to teach and genuinely help people, not solve petty syntax errors.

Comment: @Ignacio: When a user with your SO reputation recommends nonsense code, it's a burden on all of us including the OP. Other users see it and think "it *must* make sense if this guy is doing it". Then more silly questions come pouring in, rinse and repeat. This is of course assuming that you realize the code you posted is nonsense, perhaps that's not the case.

Comment: ...and as [Gumbo correctly pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673661/inbalance-of/9673720#comment12288452_9673661), isset and empty don't operate on function return values, only variables. Not your problem, sure, but here you are posting code that doesn't work, much less make sense. Not trying to be rude, I'm just disappointed to see such foolishness propagated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using Codeigniter. You've made this more complicated than it needs to be. You can reduce this to the following:

```
if( ! $this->uri->segment(3))
{
    // do something
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

> By default the function returns FALSE (boolean) if the segment does not exist.

URI segments in Codeigniter will never be empty strings, so no need to concern yourself with that. No need to trim them either.

Besides, `''` and `FALSE` are both `empty()`, so there's no need for the extra type checking.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the route for this. $route['pmsystem/viewmessage/(:num)'] = 'pmsystem/viewmessage/$1';  for a page that is located on http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/pmsystem/viewmessage/1 as 1 is the id of the message

Comment: You've sure been working on that KOW Manager for a long time. What kind of issue are you having? Whatever it is, it's not related to anything in this thread.